# How to create page in backend via WPBakery

Tags: wordpress, backend, shortcode, visual-composer, visual-editor

I'm developing a plugin that creates pages for admin menu in backend via  WPBakery. But when I look at generated page there is only shortcodes. How can I make plugins shortcodes execute in backend.

I've tried to use `echo do_shortcode( '$content' )` but it does not work. I probably should work with plugins classes but do not know how.

I want to make a page with page builder for admin menu and execute all shortcodes that creates rows columns message boxes etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before using do_shortcode, add WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes(); function, this function loads all elements, and then do_shortcode should work fine.

Comment: @ПавелИванов Yes, figured it out myself a day ago, but thanks anyway. You could also write it as an answer so I could mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ok, great. Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using do_shortcode, add WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes(); function, this function loads all elements, and then do_shortcode should work fine.